# Change loading of images from top to bottom, to left - right

Tags: javascript, css

I am using this tutorial http://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/ to create a grid with lazyload as you can see here in action http://jsfiddle.net/gaz2A/

The problem is that the images are loaded like

```
1|3|5|7
2|4|6|8
```

instead of

```
1|2|3|4
5|6|7|8
```

and leaves the start screen blank at the most part.

How can I change this ?

*I tried masonry plugin with infinite scroll, however I do not want to rely on static pages, so masonry is not a choice for me.

Comment: why don't you just wait for all of the images to load and have a loading symbol?

Comment: @maxhud Because I use lazyload and I will have a huge collection of images.

Answer (score 1):

Images will load in the order they are presented in the DOM.

Either change the DOM representation so that the images are appended into DOM in the correct order (eg. side by side first), or use some JS based preloading to preload the images in the order you want.